# Is there a way to force callers of the the Set<T> constructor to provide a type parameter?

Tags: typescript

From `lib.es2015.collection.d.ts`:

```js
interface SetConstructor {
    new <T = any>(values?: readonly T[] | null): Set<T>;
    readonly prototype: Set<any>;
}
declare var Set: SetConstructor;
```

The type of `T` in `Set<T>` defaults to `any`.  However, I'd like to enforce in our project that any caller of the `Set` constructor provide the type argument.

So

```js
new Set<any>();
```

would be valid but

```js
new Set();
```

would be an error.

Is this possible in TypeScript directly? If not, is there any existing build-time tool that could be used for the same purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try next example:

```
declare global {

    interface SetConstructor {
        new(): never; // thanks @jcalz for pointing this out
        new <T>(values?: readonly T[] | null): Set<T>;
        readonly prototype: Set<any>;
    }
    var Set: SetConstructor;
}

// no compile error
const set = new Set(); // never type
set // unable to call any method, because [set] has [never] type
```

There is no compile error, however, You will be unable to call any method of [set].

Here, TypeScript treat [set] in my example as an empty value, without properties and methods.

Comment: This could have unintended consequences because of how `never` interacts with control-flow type narrowing. Using `unknown` should be safe, or `Set<unknown>` might result in more understandable error messages in the code which uses the set after constructing it.

Comment: Actually it occurs to me you could use a string literal type like `Set<'please specify a type parameter for the Set constructor'>` to get your own "error message" to show up.

Comment: Can you replace that first signature with just `new(): never`?

Comment: @kaya3 I thought about string literal error type, but then You will be able to call string methods on [set] variables.

Comment: If you're looking for something better than `never` you could consider any of the workarounds suggested in [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689), since TS doesn't currently support "invalid" or "throw" types to allow for custom error messages

Comment: @captain-yossarian no problem; I don't *think* it acts differently compared to your signature, but one never knows

Comment: @jcalz I'd willing to bet it acts exactly in the same way, your solution is much readable